# How to get the Difference blending mode?

Tags: python, pygame, color-blending

I'm trying to make a night effect for my game in Pygame. So I'm gonna blit a black image on the screen then, change its blending mode to `Difference` just like in Photoshop in order to make the screen look darker. However, I still don't know how to do that as I haven't used the blending modes in Pygame yet. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blending mode can be changed by setting the optional *special_flags* argument of [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit):

> `blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags=0) -> Rect`
> [...]
> New in pygame 1.8: Optional special_flags: `BLEND_ADD`, `BLEND_SUB`, `BLEND_MULT`, `BLEND_MIN`, `BLEND_MAX`.
> New in pygame 1.8.1: Optional special_flags: `BLEND_RGBA_ADD`, `BLEND_RGBA_SUB`, `BLEND_RGBA_MULT`, `BLEND_RGBA_MIN`, `BLEND_RGBA_MAX`, `BLEND_RGB_ADD`, `BLEND_RGB_SUB`, `BLEND_RGB_MULT`, `BLEND_RGB_MIN`, `BLEND_RGB_MAX`.
> New in pygame 1.9.2: Optional special_flags: `BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED`
> New in pygame 2.0.0: Optional special_flags: `BLEND_ALPHA_SDL2` [...]

e.g.:

```py
screen.blit(image, (x, y), special_flags = pygame.BLEND_RGBA_SUB)
```

---

Unfortunately, Pygame doesn't have a blending mode that gives the absolute difference of 2 images. However it can be achieved with

`MAX(SUB(image1, imgage2), SUB(image2, image1))`

e.g.:

[image][image]

```py
image1 = pygame.image.load('image2.png')
image2 = pygame.image.load('image1.png')
temp_image = image1.copy() 
temp_image.blit(image2, (0, 0), special_flags = pygame.BLEND_RGBA_SUB)
final_image = image2.copy() 
final_image.blit(image1, (0, 0), special_flags = pygame.BLEND_RGBA_SUB)
final_image.blit(temp_image, (0, 0), special_flags = pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MAX)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but does this mean that the Difference mode isn't available ?

Comment: `BLEND_RGBA_SUB` is the closest you can get